# From web3/Javascript to zkSync-web3/Typescript

Tags: hardhat-deploy, typescript, zksync

I am trying to port some javascript tests targeting the Ethereum mainnet to the new zkSync testnet. This was not a problem with my standard javascript hardhat testing. Moving to typescript/zkSync, I have a problem.

I create a wallet with account_0, account_1, etc. The default account if not specified is account_0, and it works in typescript:

mySolidityContract.fund({value: "30000000000000000"});

If I try to use a different account it fails. It also fails when I specify the account as "account_0", so it's not a lack of eth, etc. Thus, this does not work:

mySolidityContract.(account_2).fund({value: "30000000000000000"});

If you know how to fix this, I would greatly appreciate it.